# Elements Alignment in Java Applet

Tags: java, swing, applet, alignment, layout-manager

[image][image]I am trying to align several elements in a Java Applet, I am not able to do it. Please help me. Here is my code:

```
public class User extends JApplet implements ActionListener,ItemListener  {

             public int sentp,recievedp,corruptedp;
             public String stetus;
             public double energi,nodeid,en;
             TextField name,time,initene,ampco,acttran;
             Button rsbt,vlbt,insd ;
             Choice ch,ch2;
             public String patrn;
             public void init() {

                 this.setSize(800,600);

                 Label namep= new Label("\n\nEnter the No. of Nodes: ", Label.CENTER);

                 name = new TextField(5);
                 Label timep = new Label("\n\nEnter time of Simulation: ",Label.CENTER);
                 time = new TextField(5);    
                 Label initen  = new Label("\n\nInitial Energy Of Each Sensor Node:");
                 initene = new TextField("10^-4 Joules");
                 initene.setEditable(false);
                 Label ampcon = new Label("\n\nAmplifier Constant:");
                 ampco = new TextField("10^-12 Joules");
                 ampco.setEditable(false);
                 Label acttrans = new Label("\n\nEnergy Required To Activate Transmitter/Reciever:");
                 acttran = new TextField("50 ^ -9 Joules");
                 acttran.setEditable(false);
            Label chp = new Label("\n\nSelect Radio Model:",Label.CENTER);
               rsbt = new Button("Run The Simulation");

             ch= new Choice();

             ch.add("");
             ch.add("Gaussian RadioModel");
             ch.add("Rayleigh RadioModel");
             Label pat= new Label("\n\nDistribution Pattern");
             ch2= new Choice();
             ch2.add("");
             ch2.add("Rectangular Pattern");
             ch2.add("Linear Pattern");
             ch2.add("Random Pattern");

             vlbt=new Button("ViewLog");
             insd=new Button("Details of node");
           JPanel cp = new JPanel();
          this.add(cp);
             GridBagLayout gridb = new GridBagLayout();
             Container cont = getContentPane();
            cont.setLayout(gridb);
            add(cp);

            GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(cp);
         cp.setLayout(layout);


             layout.setAutoCreateGaps(true);
             layout.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);
     layout.setVerticalGroup(
       layout.createSequentialGroup()



       .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup()
.addComponent(namep)
.addComponent(name)
.addComponent(rsbt))
.addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
.addComponent(timep)
.addComponent(time)
.addComponent(vlbt))
.addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
.addComponent(chp)
.addComponent(ch))
.addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
.addComponent(pat)
.addComponent(ch2))
.addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
.addComponent(initen)
.addComponent(initene))
.addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
.addComponent(ampcon)
.addComponent(ampco))
.addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
.addComponent(acttrans)
.addComponent(acttran))
);


          rsbt.addActionListener(this);
          vlbt.addActionListener(this);
          insd.addActionListener(this);
          ch.addItemListener(this);   
            ch2.addItemListener(this); 
 }
```

Comment: 1) That code does not even compile 2) What is the current alignment and what would be the desired results (screenshots could certainly make things clearer) 3) why using AWT components and not Swing components 4) Please use self-describing names for your variables so your code becomes readable. The fact `acttran` is a `TextField` is not straightforward (same for all other variables)

Comment: Please provide a visual description of what exactly you want and where ? Except for `JApplet` nothing relates to `Swing` :(

Comment: Please check it. My applet is as shown above. The elements in it are not aligned properly. How to align them using Layouts in java? I tried with the above mentioned code but not getting it. Shall I give the old applet code also?

Comment: In the screenshot they are aligned (horizontally), but obviously not the alignment you want. Please describe the alignment you want to achieve (even a MS Paint mock-up would clarify the question). Also take a look at the [Swing visual guide to layout managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) which probably contains an example of the alignment you want

Comment: @Robin: I wanted to align them as shown in the later image.Do you want the code what I have written so that you can point out the modifications to be made?

Comment: I think an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) would help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this, is this good for you :

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class AppletLayout extends JApplet
{
    private JTextField noNodeField;
    private JTextField timeSimField;
    private JTextField iniEngField;
    private JTextField ampConsField;
    private JTextField engReqField; 

    private JComboBox selModeCombo;
    private JComboBox distPattCombo;

    private JButton runSimButton;
    private JButton logButton;
    private JButton detailNodeButton;

    private String[] selectionModelString = {"", "Gaussian RadioModel"
                                               , "Rayleigh RadioModel"};

    private String[] distPatternString = {"", "Rectangular Pattern"
                                               , "Linear Pattern"
                                               , "Random Pattern"}; 


    public void init()
    {
        try
        {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    createAndDisplayGUI();
                }
            });
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.err.println("Unable to Create and Display GUI : " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void createAndDisplayGUI()
    {
        JLabel noNodeLabel = new JLabel("Enter the No. of Nodes :", JLabel.LEFT);
        noNodeField = new JTextField(5);

        JLabel timeSimLabel = new JLabel("Enter time of Simulation :", JLabel.LEFT);
        timeSimField = new JTextField(5);

        JLabel iniEngLabel = new JLabel("Initial Energy Of Each Sensor Node :", JLabel.LEFT);
        iniEngField = new JTextField("10^-4 Joules");

        JLabel ampConsLabel = new JLabel("Amplifier Constant :", JLabel.LEFT);
        ampConsField = new JTextField("10^-12 Joules");

        JLabel engReqLabel = new JLabel("Energy Required To Activate Transmitter/Reciever :", JLabel.LEFT);
        engReqField = new JTextField("50 ^ -9 Joules");

        JLabel selModeLabel = new JLabel("Select Radio Model :", JLabel.LEFT);
        selModeCombo = new JComboBox(selectionModelString);

        JLabel distPattLabel = new JLabel("Distribution Pattern :", JLabel.LEFT);
        distPattCombo = new JComboBox(selectionModelString);

        runSimButton = new JButton("Run Simulation");
        logButton = new JButton("View Log");
        detailNodeButton = new JButton("Details of Node");

        JComponent contentPane = (JComponent) getContentPane();

        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
        topPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        topPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2));
        topPanel.add(noNodeLabel);
        topPanel.add(noNodeField);
        topPanel.add(timeSimLabel);
        topPanel.add(timeSimField);
        topPanel.add(iniEngLabel);
        topPanel.add(iniEngField);
        topPanel.add(ampConsLabel);
        topPanel.add(ampConsField);
        topPanel.add(engReqLabel);
        topPanel.add(engReqField);
        topPanel.add(selModeLabel);
        topPanel.add(selModeCombo);
        topPanel.add(distPattLabel);
        topPanel.add(distPattCombo);
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        //buttonPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(buttonPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1, 5, 5));
        buttonPanel.add(runSimButton);
        buttonPanel.add(logButton);
        buttonPanel.add(detailNodeButton);

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
        mainPanel.add(topPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        mainPanel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_END);

        contentPane.add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

        setSize(1000, 600);
    }
}
```

Here is the output :

[image: JAPPLET]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I wanted this one. Thanks again for your reply and concern.

Comment: You're MOST WELCOME, Glad this example did helped you, KEEP SMILING :-)

Comment: thank u so much. One more please:  Since each row (of JLabel and JTextField) in topPanel are so close to each other. I tried adding top and bottom padding between the rows using setBorder() method for each label and TextField as you shown. But I didn't get.Is there any other way to achieve it?

Comment: Simply change this line `topPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2));` to this `topPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2, 15, 15));` or provide anything other than `15`, that will do, what you want, it seems :-) . I hope that is what you referring to :-)

Comment: @Doug : `Content Pane` is basically a `Container` that is present as one of the `panes` on the Top-level Containers, more info can be found in [Top-level Container Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html#contentpane). `getContentPane()` simply returns the `Container` boject of the top-level containers i.e. `JFrame/JWindow/JDialog`. It is a good practice, to add various components to a `JPanel` and then set this `JPanel` as the content pane of the top-level container, instead of doing it the way I did in this example. I just modified a bit of OP's code

Answer (score 3):

When you say this

```
JPanel cp = new JPanel();
```

it means you're going to get a `FlowLayout` automatically. You probably want a [different one](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

Edit: OK, I can see where you're giving `cp` a `GroupLayout`, but I don't see where you `pack()` the window that `cp` is in or call `setVisible()`.

Edit: But that doesn't matter for an applet.

Answer (score 3):

Your current code looks pretty much like you are using some sort of GUI builder tool to generate the final layout.

For maximum control, build the component and add them to the panel. If you are looking to use GridBagLayout as shown in your code then follow the sequence construct as shown below

```
JPanel p1 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
GridBagConstraints cs = new GridBagConstraints();
    cs.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    lblUsername = new JLabel("Name: ");
    cs.gridx = 0;
    cs.gridy = 0;
    cs.gridwidth = 1;
    p1.add(lblUsername, cs);

    txtUsername = new JTextField("", 20);
    cs.gridx = 1;
    cs.gridy = 0;
    cs.gridwidth = 2;
    p1.add(txtUsername, cs);
   ...
   add(cp);
```

Or alternatively use BorderLayout or FlowLayout to hold the components on your panel:

```
JPanel p1 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
p1.add(lblUsername, BorderLaout.EAST);
...
```